# Why does Django think my query string is empty?

Tags: python, django, query-string

I've been having trouble with a query string in one of my views in Django. I've successfully handled query strings in other views, so I'm not sure what I did wrong here. I stripped things down to a really basic view, and I'm still not getting anything.

My URL:

```
localhost/query_view/?foo=foo
```

My template:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>{{ query_string }}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My view:

```python
def query_view(request):
    query_string = request.META['QUERY_STRING']
    return render(request, 'query_view.html', {'query_string': query_string})
```

I should expect `foo=foo` to be displayed on the page, right? Currently, I'm getting nothing.

**Edit:** Django version 1.9.4, Python version 3.4.3

Comment: have you tried print `request.META['QUERY_STRING']`?

Comment: @HaifengZhang Also returns nothing.

Comment: does `request.GET['foo']` give you `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 def query_view(request):
     query_string = request.GET.get('foo',None)
     print(query_string)
     return render(request, 'query_view.html', {'query_string': query_string})
```

and check if query_string value is None or not .

Let me know, if it didn't work out!

Inaddition  mention your django and python version also.

Comment: Ok, it does return None.

Comment: try with some other urls like localhost/view/?foo=foo , localhost/view/?foo=bar , localhost/view/?foo='foo' , localhost/view/?foo=1234 and see if any of this working ?

Comment: can you mention your urls.py specifically your url? also ensure your url is not matching with any other urls coming above that .

Comment: `url(r'^query_view/', views.query_view, name='query_view'),` and it does not match any other urls.

Comment: are you sure that your request is going to query_view(request) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146205/discussion-between-tom-and-called2voyage).

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely certain. I can't use stackoverflow chat, it's blocked at my work. But stackexchange chat works: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60148/discussion-between-tom-and-called2voyage

Answer (score 2):

I would put a debugger before the return to see what's actually in the request. But usually something like `request.GET.get('foo')` would get you what you want. Also, you can provide a default value if `foo` is actually empty. `request.GET.get('foo', 'blah')`

Comment: Also returns nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: I wish I could provide more information, but I'm not sure what else would be relevant since my other views are working fine. If you need more information on my environment or anything else, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, your answer ended up being correct, but tom helped me work through my problem so I gave him the checkmark.